# Access result later in pipe

Tags: r, magrittr

### Access result later in pipe

I am trying to create functions which print the number of rows excluded in a dataset at each step in a pipe.

Something like this:

```
iris %>% 
    function_which_save_nrows_and_return_the_data() %>% 
    filter(exclude some rows) %>% 
    function_which_prints_difference_in_rows_before_after_exlusion_and_returns_data %>% 
    function_which_save_nrows_and_return_the_data() %>% 
    function_which_prints_difference_in_rows_before_after_exlusion_and_returns_data  ...etc
```

These are the functions I have attempted:

```
n_before = function(x) {assign("rows", nrow(x), .GlobalEnv); return(x)}

n_excluded = function(x) { 
    print(rows - nrow(x))
    return(x)
}
```

This successfully saves the object rows:

[image]

But if I add two more links, the object is NOT saved:

[image]

So how can I create and access the rows-object later the pipe?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to R's lazy evaluation.  It occurs even if pipes are not used.  See code below.  In that code the argument to `n_excluded` is `filter(n_before(iris), Species != 'setosa')` and at the point that `rows` is used in the `print` statement the argument has not been referenced from within `n_excluded` so the entire argument will not have been evaluated and so `rows` does not yet exist.

```
if (exists("rows")) rm(rows)  # ensure rows does not exist
n_excluded(filter(n_before(iris), Species != 'setosa'))
## Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
##   error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 
##   'print': object 'rows' not found
```

To fix this

**1)** we can force x before the `print` statement.

```
n_excluded = function(x) { 
  force(x)
  print(rows - nrow(x))
  return(x)
}
```

**2)** Alternately, we can use the magrittr sequential pipe which guarantees that legs are run in order.  magrittr makes it available but does not provide an operator for it but we can assign it to an operator like this.

```
`%s>%` <- magrittr::pipe_eager_lexical
iris %>%
  n_before() %>%
  filter(Species != 'setosa') %s>%  # note use of %s>% on this line
  n_excluded()
```

The magrittr developer has stated that he will add it as an operator if there is sufficient demand for it so you might want to add such request to magrittr issue [#247](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/247) on github.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the extended capabilities of `pipeR`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(pipeR)
  
n_excluded = function(x) { 
  print(rows - nrow(x))
  return(x)
}

p <- iris %>>%
   (~rows=nrow(.)) %>>%
   filter(Species != "setosa") %>>%
   n_excluded()
```